# Gitlab mirroring remove slash from ssh:// URL

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I configured my Gitlab CE repository to mirror in push mode to `ssh://git@git.host/dir/repo.git` and it seems that the remote host sees git commands to `/dir/repo.git`. However my repo lives in `dir/repo.git`.

Is there a way to remove the leading "/" from the Gitlab mirror URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if a SCP syntax would work better:

```
git@git.host:dir/repo.git
```

That should force the remote host to use `dir/repo.git`

The [OP thodg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248701/thodg) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591794/gitlab-mirroring-remove-slash-from-ssh-url/61606681#comment109259642_61606681):

> bare repo only accessible through ssh

In that case, you need the full absolute path to `dir/repo.git`:

```
git@git.host:/full/path/to/dir/repo.git
```

Comment: unfortunately the Gitlab web interface does not allow remote URLs without a leading protocol specifier.

Comment: @thodg What is the nature of `git.host`: is that remote host with a private GitLab instance? Or Gitea? Or just some bare repositories?

Comment: bare repo only accessible through ssh

Comment: unfortunately my ssh git service won't accept absolute pathnames. The URL handling in Gitlab is broken IMHO.